# How to disable text formatting when pasting in summernote editor?

Tags: editor, summernote

How to disable text formatting when pasting in summernote editor?
how to turn off text formatting, for example when you paste with word, etc. adds a bunch of unnecessary styles all the time. Is it possible to make it paste plain text without formatting?

Answer (score 0):

By using `summernote.paste` event we can track the paste in the editor and then text can be formatted or unnecessary style can be removed.

```
 $('#id').on('summernote.paste', function(e, ne) {
        //get the text
        let inputText = ((ne.originalEvent || ne).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
        // block default behavior
        ne.preventDefault();
        //modify paste text as plain text
        let modifiedText = inputText .replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>');
        //put it back in editor
        document.execCommand('insertHtml', false, modifiedText );
    })
```